# No context menu in Windows 7 for TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, contextmenu

I'm using [Windows 7 Ultimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions) 64-bit. I've installed the most recent 64-bit version of TortoiseSVN from the official site, restarted the PC and can't see a SVN context menu even when shift-right clicking.

I've uninstalled this version and tried with 32 bit one, but still no luck.

They [say in the FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#nomenus) it happens when you install the 32-bit application on a 64-bit [OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), but I've tried both and none works!

There's [a movie on YouTube showing installation process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lKZjnaXVrc) and many comments with the same problem below. So I guess I'm not alone, but I'm not able to Google for right answer.

What do I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62392862/761095 if you upgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.14.0.

Answer (score 17):

For several updates of Tortoise this happened for me, too. I'm using Windows 7-64 and the 64 bit version of Tortoise.
A solution on several PCs was to run the Install 2 times (without uninstalling inbetween).
After the second install, everything works fine again.

Comment: +1 this is true. And here is why: (for the sake of completion) http://tortoisesvn.net/majorupgrade

Comment: +1, I ran into this when upgrading tortoise a few weeks ago. installing twice fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

I normally have to perform a *Repair* after installing TortoiseSVN.

Comment: This worked for me too for the Tortoise version 1.9.3

Comment: Also, I found that context menu was working in the files open with dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and installing/repair multiple times did not work for me.

The solution for me was registry permissions, as documented here:

[TortoiseSVN right click menu gone when selecting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434780/tortoisesvn-right-click-menu-gone-when-selecting-files)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install a 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN on Windows 7. I expected to see the context menu (on right click) after the installation, which was not the case. Though I have tried to do this earlier on a Windows XP-based PC and it worked, on Windows 7 this was not working.

I tried to install/uninstall/re-install/ TortoiseSVN several times and restarted the PC each time as well. Still, it did not work.

I tried to repair the installation, as mentioned in the above post. Then, on right-click I see the TortoiseSVN context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Download ShellExView and check whether you enable Tortoise SVN or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with right click TortoiseSVN.exe > Properties > Run Application as Administrator.

Edit:
Poked around and found this: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=2420343

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people which those solutions has no effect (which was my case). In my case the problem was very silly. In order to appear the context menu, the destination folder MUST be under source control.

Therefore in my case the solution was just to set the destination folder under source control just with:

"Right Click" -> TortoiseSVN -> Add...

And afterwards when moving the file to that folder using the right button, the "context menu" appeared.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After installing, repairing and all the hustle that's suggested here (unsuccessfully) I thought I might as well try to start the actual application to see if there was some "secret" setting to activate the missing context menu icons.

All I got was an error message of Windows (Windows 10 Ultimate 64) that there was obviously something wrong  with an missing DLL.

No wonder that the right click entries are missing when the relying program itself is buggy.

So I installed the second newest version (in my case: [1.12.2 64](https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/storage/1.12.2/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.12.2.28653-x64-svn-1.12.2.msi/)) and voila, it works. right click icons back again!

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is install TortoiseSVN, then reboot the computer then context menu will show up.

Comment: aldona22 has already mentioned that he/she tried reinstalling and restarting which didn't work. Did you miss any part of your answer ? Thanks

Comment: This might not work for the OP but it did for me, I would keep it under the list of possible solutions.