# TortoiseSVN right click menu gone when selecting files

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, 64-bit

**Short Question**
Has anyone had an issue when right clicking files (.c/.h/etc..) and the TortoiseSVN menu is not present?  Note that it **is** there when I right click a folder in the same directory.

**Failed Attempts**
I have seen that a number of issues like this have been resolved by running the installer again and selecting `repair` or `modify`,  at this point neither of these attempts have worked.

**Is there anything else I can try to get this working again?** The DIFF functionality being gone is hurting something fierce.

**Edit**
I am the only developer working on the files.  I actually found a way to see the diff: Move the parent folder TortoiseSVN->Check for modifications.  This menu does indeed show all of my versioned files as well as any of them that have been modified.

I have also confirmed that the files really still are version controlled by checking out the same repo in on a different machine.

**Edit2**
It is worth noting that I am using [Macdrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) and it's right click menu is present all the time.  In addition, I just saw that I am having the same issue with TortoiseGIT as well.

Comment: I had the same problem as you, and I solved it by fixing the permissions on the registry entry as described here http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=2855263&dsForumId=4061&viewType=browseAll&currentPage=1&countPerPage=25&totalPages=2.

Comment: @TBTB Holy carp... That did it.  Be sure to answer the question and I'll accept it. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to registry editor using regedit
2. Go to and click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/​shellex/ContextMenuH​andlers/TortoiseSVN
3. Observe error message box saying access is denied.
4. Right click on the key mentioned above, go to "Permissions"...
5. In the permission dialog, click on "Advanced"
6. Click on "Owner" tab, click on your account and click "Apply"
7. OK the dialog
8. Right click on the key mentioned above, go to "Permissions"...
9. Grant permissions for OWNER RIGHTS to "Full Control"
10. Apply the changes

[Source](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=2855263&dsForumId=4061&viewType=browseAll&currentPage=1&countPerPage=25&totalPages=2)

Comment: What if no error message is displayed?
I checked my user's permissions and they are set to full already. Not sure if you could help me out.

Comment: @Tycon712 The initial thought if the error message didn't pop up is either it's the wrong key or this isn't the root problem.  I know it's not much help... I gave up working on Windows and am at home and happy with Mac.

Comment: Nice one, had this problem with git and svn for about 5 months. First one thats actually made a differece

Answer (score 2):

If still not works so try to use shift key + right click.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that these files under version control? It is possible that someone has deleted these files from svn repo and after update your these files has become unversioned.

You can check that by going one dir level up (from folder where these files are located) and choose whether **Tortoise-SVN**->**Repo-Browser menu** (check that they are present on SVN server) or **SVN Commit** (make sure **Show unversioned files** checkbox is set and check **Text Status** Column if it contains "non-versioned") .

Comment: I am sure the files are under version control.  Check out my edit.

Comment: Then it's definitely a windows issue. You cannot see TSVN menu for all files in working dir? Can you checkout and check another svn url?

Comment: As long as I do not right click a file yes.  Meaning I can right click on white space in the working dir and Update, Commit, and the full list of SVN commands (just like when I select the parent folder).

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Right click on the folder which you want to checkout click TortoiseSVN --> settings --> Context Menu --> uncheck the Hide menus for unversioned paths