# Can't see TortoiseSVN in right-click of Windows shell

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, windows-shell

**Problem:**

1. I was trying to install [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN)  and had a problem as specified in a previous post, *[TortoiseSVN doesn't work properly in Windows 7 32-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156649/tortoise-svn-doesnt-work-properly-in-windows-7-32-bit-version?noredirect=1#comment23150587_16156649)*.
2. Now even after **uninstalling and reinstalling** multiple times, I can't see TortoiseSVN in **my right-click of Windows shell**
3. When I install the software, I end up seeing only `TSVNCache.exe` running in the background. I am not able to open `Tortoise-SVN -->Settings`.

I have a suspicion that a registry key is corrupted.

How do I verify whether a `registry key` is corrupted or not? Why doesn't `Tortoise-svn` show up?

Note: I have installed the **32-bit version on Windows 7** and verified `file-integrity` and followed all `instructions`.

Comment: You are apparently not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605278/tortoise-svn-no-context-menu-in-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: But my problem is, i neither see in `right-click on desktop` nor `right-click on folder directory`

Comment: I have downloaded `shellview` and verifed that my `tortoise svn` is enabled and was under type `context menu`. but still not able to get it. I don't want to play with registry files , as it could break my system.

Comment: Is mandatory to use TortoiseSVN? Have you tried another client? http://svn-ref.assembla.com/windows-svn-client-reviews.html