# Missing TortoiseSVN context menu after upgrading to 1.14.0

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN does not work after upgrading to version 1.14.0. Its context menu is missing in Windows after upgrading to version 1.14.0, and the following errors occur:

> TortoiseProc.exe - System Error The code execution cannot proceed
> because libapr_tsvn.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may
> fix this problem.
>
> TortoiseProc.exe - System Error The code execution cannot proceed
> because libaprutil_tsvn.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program
> may fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was fixed in TortoiseSVN 1.14.1.

---

**Outdated answer:**

> The problem was resolved in [r28894](https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/scm/svn/commits/28894), and a nightly build with the
> fix is available. However, an official patch update is not available
> yet. Unfortunately, there is no ETA known for TortoiseSVN's patch
> update release. See the discussion at
> https://groups.google.com/g/tortoisesvn/c/EK6gjTCQXlg/m/Phjse8lEBAAJ

The problem should be fixed in a patch update. Right now you can solve this problem by repairing TortoiseSVN 1.14.0 via Windows Installer. See the article [KB169: Missing TortoiseSVN context menu after upgrading to 1.14.0](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00169/) for more information.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to **Control Panel | Programs and Features**,
2. Find **TortoiseSVN 1.14.0** in the list of installed applications,
3. Run the **Repair** command for TortoiseSVN 1.14.0. The problem will be solved when the repair is done.

Alternatively, you can start the TortoiseSVN 1.14.0 MSI (e.g., TortoiseSVN-1.14.0.28885-x64-svn-1.14.0.msi) and select the **Repair** command.

Note that *in some cases you may need to restart the computer* after repairing TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @magicandre1981 nightly TortoiseSVN builds are not signed - this can be a problem.

Comment: 1.14.1 is out, which includes the fix from last years nightlies.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still there, I got it when reinstalling tortoise because the commandline tools where missing. I had to completely remove and reinstall tortoise to fix it (file TortoiseSVN-1.10.5.28651-x64-svn-1.10.6.msi).